# Can cached AMP pages allow resource hints to warm up navigation to the canonical site?

Tags: amp-html

Can cached AMP pages allow resource hints to warm up navigation to the canonical site? Example using [link rel= "preload/preconnect/etc."]?

Answer (score 0):

- Currently resource hints are not allowed for cached AMP pages. The AMP Cache removes any resource hints in the original document. [[Reference GitHub Link]](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cache-modifications.md#remove-tags-and-attributes)
- In Chrome, as a work-around ServiceWorker can be used to achieve the same behavior.

  - Page specific assets can be passed via query parameters to "amp-install-serviceworker" component’s ‘data-iframe-src’ attribute, which shall then pass this on to the service worker.
  - The "amp-install-serviceworker" component enables service worker installation via same origin or via the Google AMP Cache. Service workers can run in the background even when the browser is closed, cache required contents in advance of rendering time, send notifications to users, and more.
  - When the document is accessed via the Google AMP Cache, the HTML document noted in the data-iframe-src attribute is used to install the service worker. The reason why amp-install-serviceworker requires a separate data-iframe-src option is because browsers can't install service worker from other domains for security reasons.
  - "amp-install-serviceworker" doesn't load Service Workers until after the page becomes visible. That is Service Worker doesn’t boot for pre-rendering.
- However, as a recommendation, precaching common assets should offer a sufficient speed up.
- Below are resource links that details out on implementation for
  "amp-install-serviceworker"

  - [ampbyexample.com](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-install-serviceworker/)
  - [ampproject.org](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-install-serviceworker)

Comment: Note that using the service worker to pre-cache resources in this way is unlikely to work with future versions of Safari ([more info](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13369)).